# How to adress the # Map variable via a function?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

How to adress the # Map variable via a function.

Consider the following function:

```
sf3[n_,fun_]:=Map[Map[fun[#]&,Range[Floor[n/#]]]&,Range[n]]
```

Now

```
sf3[4,# &]
```

returns

```
{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}, {1}, {1}}
```

as expected.

Also,

```
sf3[4, Floor[4/#] &]
```

returns

```
{{4, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 2}, {4}, {4}}
```

as expected.

I want to know how to address the inner map variable such that I can create:

```
{ 
{Floor[4/1], Floor[4/2], Floor[4/3], Floor[4/4]},
{Floor[2/1], Floor[2/2]},
{Floor[1/1]},
{Floor[1/1]}
}
```

So, the

```
Floor[4/#] in sf3[4, Floor[4/#] &]
```

should be something like

```
Floor[Inner#/#].
```

?

Comment: I do not understand what you want to accomplish. What is your ultimate goal here, and what is the expected output from applying your envisioned function to the list of lists of `Floor` expressions you gave?

Comment: Why write `Map[fun[#]&, ...]` instead of `Map[fun, ...]`?

Comment: Because it works, does not help b.t.w.

Comment: @MarcoB It is one ( there are at least 3 ) way of expressing the Sum from 1 to n, and for eacht of those the sum from a function applied to the divisors of these numbers. - See Tom Apostol - Introduction to Analytic Number Theory Chapter 3 (par.10 / par. 13) Theorem 3.11 or other books on the field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I understand the question in its entirety so I'm only going to produce a few notes that will hopefully provide some insight into the problem the way I see it.

Starting from the title of the *Q.*-if I get it right-this is an issue I struggle with *all* the time and the solution I usually use is `With`.

Consider the following code

```
Map[f[#]&, Range[5]]
```

This code snippet-*I think*-is very similar to the original code used in the definition of function `sf3` if we allow for `f = Map[g[#]&, Range[h[#]]]&` and set `h = RandomInteger[{1, #}]&` for the moment; the only difference is that the respective functions are-in a sense-*really* simple and straightforward. For the sake of completeness, evaluating the code above in `BlockRandom[<code above>, RandomSeeding -> 123456798]` produces

> ```
> {{g[1]}, {g[1]}, {g[1]}, {g[1], g[2]}, {g[1], g[2], g[3], g[4], g[5]}}
> ```

Now, consider what is happening in the first argument of `Map` in `Map[f[#]&, Range[5]]`: `f` receives as input sequentially the elements of `{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}`; each integer is *then* used as an argument *inside* `f` eg for `i=1` `f[1]` evaluates to `Map[g[#]&, Range[h[1]]]` which in turn we'll assume evaluates further to `Map[g[#]&, {1}]&` (remember, `h` returns a random integer in the range `{1, 1}` *this* time and the output cannot be anything else but `1` and `Range[1]` is `{1}`). Next, the *inner* `Map` applies `g`-*its* first argument-on the elements of `{1}` sequentially which-*this time*-obviously evaluates simply to `{g[1]}`.

Ok, the point of this narration of the evaluation steps is to set the focus on what is available when `g` is going to evaluate; we know the input to `g` in the example above is `1` *but* there is also **another** value available: that is the argument of `f` from the outer `Map`; *that* value in the example above is *also* `1`.

The problem in the code above is that when `g` evaluates, it cannot see that initial `1`. `g` can only *see* the elements of the second argument of the inner `Map` ie the elements of list `{1}`.

So, **if that's the problem** with the code in the *Q.* my proposed solution is quite simple: define `f` as in `f = With[{in = #}, Map[g[#, in]&, Range[h[in]]]]&` and optionally allow `g` to receive an extra argument.

With that definition for `f`, the `Map[f[#]&, Range[5]]` inside `BlockRandom[<code above>, RandomSeeding -> 123456798]` evaluates to

> ```
> {{g[1, 1]}, {g[1, 2]}, {g[1, 3]}, {g[1, 4], g[2, 4]}, {g[1, 5], g[2, 5], g[3, 5], g[4, 5], g[5, 5]}}
> ```

Therefore, my answer to the question in the title is to use `With`. Alternatively, one could define the analog to my `f` as a function with a local scope using `Module` and use local variables that will eventually be visible in deeper nested scopes.

## End notes

I used the following function to replicate the various output in the *Q*. and I was able to replicate `{{Floor[4/1], Floor[4/2], Floor[4/3], Floor[4/4]},{Floor[2/1], Floor[2/2]},{Floor[1/1]},{Floor[1/1]}}`

```
sf3Do[f_, n_] := Reap[
  Do[
    Sow[
      Reap[
        Do[
          Sow[f[j, i]], {j, 1, Floor[n/i]}]] // Rest], {i, 1, n}]
 ] // Rest /* (Flatten[#, 4] &)
```

Evaluating `sf3Do[# &, 4]` produces `{{1, 2, 3, 4}, {1, 2}, {1}, {1}}` and `sf3Do[Floor[4/#] &, 4]` produces `{{4, 2, 1, 1}, {4, 2}, {4}, {4}}` as expected.

Also, evaluating `sf3Do[Floor[Floor[4/ #1]/#2] &, 4]` produces the desired output of `{{4, 2, 1, 1}, {2, 1}, {1}, {1}}`.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 1):

Unlikely this is what you're looking for but it might push things on a bit.

```
sf3[n_, fun_] := Map[Map[fun[Length[r]/ToString[#]] &,
    r = Range[Floor[n/#]]] &, Range[n]]

sf3[4, floor[#] &]
```

> ```
> {{floor[4/1], floor[4/2], floor[4/3], floor[4/4]},
>  {floor[2/1], floor[2/2]},
>  {floor[1/1]},
>  {floor[1/1]}}
> ```

Comment: I will study this later today ( very early on Sunday at CET right now ), thank you. I have updated the question, perhaps I was not clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

Wrap `#` with `Defer` or `HoldForm` in the second argument:

```
sf3[4, Floor[4/Defer[#]] &]
```

> ```
> {{Floor[4/1], Floor[4/2], Floor[4/3], Floor[4/4]}, 
>   {Floor[4/1], Floor[4/2]}, 
>   {Floor[4/1]}, 
>   {Floor[4/1]}}
> ```

Comment: This is what I get at the moment, but not what I am looking for. Pls. look again. ( Upvoted? )

Answer (score 0):

```
sf3[4, Floor[HoldForm[4/#]] &] // TableForm
```

[image: table]

Use [`ReleaseHold`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ReleaseHold.html) to evaluate as usual in Mathematica.

```
{#, #} & /@ sf3[4, Floor[4/#] &][[1]]

{{4, 4}, {2, 2}, {1, 1}, {1, 1}}

sf3hp[{x_, y_}] := sf3[y, Floor[x/HoldForm[#]] &]

Map[sf3hp[#][[1, 1]] &, {#, #} & /@ 
   sf3[4, Floor[4/#] &][[1]]] // TableForm
```

gives together the output:

[image: output as demanded]

Comment: It is essential that it goes through SF3. So second and third options are not relevant.